# $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(xy)(f(x)-f(y))=(x-y)f(x)f(y)$

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

$\textbf{Question:}$

Find all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that,
$f(xy)(f(x)-f(y))=(x-y)f(x)f(y)$ holds for all real number $x,y$

$\textbf{My progress:}$
If we substitute $y=1$ we get $f(x)(f(x)-xf(1))=0$ which implies

$f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=kx$ for some real $k$.

But what it doesn't say is that,whether for all $x$ it is $0$ or for all $x$ it is $kx$ aka maybe for some $x$ its $0$ and for some other its $kx.$

Then,I thought I can arrive at some sort of contradiction and prove the answer will be $kx$ for all $x$  and some real $k$.But I failed in this attempt.

In addition to helping me with this problem I would really appreciate if someone gives me some reference from where I can learn in general how to solve such tricky situations.(as I have seen such situation in some other problems too)

Comment: It was a bit more complicated than I first though and it seem you do get solutions that are combinations of the two you have found. You can find an argument here (search for Problem 267) https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h350187p2691627

Comment: Is $0 = kx$ when $k = 0$?

Comment: yes,why shouldn't it?

Comment: You can avoid such tricky situations by not looking at functional equations.